# How to Dynamically set to Field in Oracle apex 5.1 button

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have button in a page that will send an email. I have created a process for sending email (which is in built). The email is working fine.

My problem now is to assign to based on the form item (P5_email).
[image]

Also on the Email body, i would want to dynamically update the text based on the Items on the page

Anyone with the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter substitution string `&P5_EMAIL.` in *Body Plain Text* property of Send Email Process to include dynamic content in your text.